# Icon Fonts for programming languages

Tags: css, html, fonts, icons

I am creating a HTML 5 personal page.

As I believe that we should write the minimal code possible and that there is nothing we do that someone has not already done I ask if anyone know a set of icons for programming languages that can be used as a font in my HTML page.

For example:
I use [Font Awesome](http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/icons/) and I get all the icons I want in my page, it is simple and gorgeous and my code and folder remain clean, however there are no icons for programming languages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I'd suggest is looking up SVG icons of the languages you want via your search engine of choice ([example found after 5 seconds on DuckDuckGo](https://www.iconfinder.com/iconsets/scripting-and-programming-languages)) and following that, using a tool like [IcoMoon](https://icomoon.io) to actually convert them into a custom icon font. There are also lots of free icons ready to select from inside the app itself.

If you're more of a command line person, you will probably appreciate [Font Custom](http://fontcustom.com/).

Comment: *'This domain name expired on Oct 02 2015 03:18AM'* - http://fontcustom.com/

Answer (score 5):

You can use [devicons](http://vorillaz.github.io/devicons/) fonts. it has many programming languages logos:

http://vorillaz.github.io/devicons/

Answer (score 0):

I always use [Icon search engine and market place](https://www.iconfinder.com/) and 
[Flat Icon](http://www.flaticon.com/free-icons/programming-language_23328). It also allows you to filter by licensing.

Some other Links

[Link1](https://pictonic.co/)

[Icon Archive](http://www.iconarchive.com/tag/programming-language)

Comment: As far as I can see the Icon Archive only has bitmap images. These wouldn't work in a web font. But Flaticon looks like a good resource.

Comment: Despite the fact that it was not what i was looking for thanks, it can be useful in the future